# object is not scriptable error in python code for e-ink task display

Tags: python, todoist

I am attempting to salvage some python code to make an e-ink display of tasks from todoist. It was written for a deprecated API but adapting the call only one issue has popped up. After receiving the callback I get

```
item = str(my_task['content'])
TypeError: 'Task' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm calling the API here:

```
def query_todo_list():
    global todo_response
    global do_screen_update
    print('-= Ping ToDo API =-')
    while True:
        try:
            new_todo_response = Todo.get_tasks()
            break
        except ValueError:
            print('-= ToDo API JSON Failed - Will Try Again =-')
            time.sleep(todo_wait)
        except:
            print('-= ToDo API Too Many Pings - Will Try Again =-')
            time.sleep(refresh_time)
    if ((new_todo_response) != (todo_response)):
        print('-= Task List Change Detected =-')
        do_screen_update = 1
        todo_response = new_todo_response
        return True
```

Later on is the line I am getting the error from:

```
line_location = 20
    for my_task in todo_response:
        item = str(my_task['content'])
        priority = str(my_task['priority'])
```

I've replicated the error when trying to print the specific properties of a task, but I can print the output as a whole just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What module is ```Todo``` from?

Comment: Is this  https://github.com/Doist/todoist-api-python/tree/main/todoist_api_python the api you're referring to?

Comment: Ah, should have clarified, yes 'from todoist_api_python.api import TodoistAPI'

Comment: from my brief scan of the api, it looks like each ```my_task``` is a ```Task``` object, so perhaps you can do something like ```str(my_task.to_dict()['content'])```.  Of course, with proper error handling.

Comment: @ewokx yes, that fixed the test where I am just trying to print the 'content' thanks! Now to update all the other issues.